# Zend Framework. Fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework

Help me, please. Zend Framework output error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Resource_Exception' with message 'Bootstrap file found for module "messages" but bootstrap class "Messages_Bootstrap" not found' in
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Modules.php:82 Stack trace: #0
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(680): Zend_Application_Resource_Modules->init() #1 
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(623): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('modules') #2 
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #3 
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL) #4 
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/index.php(52): Zend_Application->bootstrap() #5 {main} thrown in 
/home/aqq10697/public_html/readder.ru/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Modules.php on line 82
```

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF has found a bootstrap class for your messages module (probably at `application/modules/messages/Bootstrap.php`). It is expecting this file to define a class called `Messages_Bootstrap`, it doesn't. Either add the class or delete the bootstrap file.

If you add the class, it'll look something like this:

```
class Messages_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```